# Gradle can't find tests in additional source set

Tags: java, gradle, junit5, source-sets

My goal is to set up a source set for integration tests. I created a source set called "intTest". I put a simple test inside:

```
package com.github.frozensync;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

class Application {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("should work")
    void foo() {
        assertEquals(2, 2);
    }
}
```

When I try to run it, I get the following error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':integrationTest'.
>   > No tests found for given includes: [com.github.frozensync.Application](filter.includeTestsMatching)
>   * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>   BUILD FAILED in 0ms

This is my project structure:
[image: project structure]

And this is my `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.github.frozensync'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    intTest {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
    }
}

idea {
    module {
        testSourceDirs += sourceSets.intTest.java.srcDirs
        testResourceDirs += sourceSets.intTest.resources.srcDirs
    }
}

configurations {
    intTestImplementation.extendsFrom implementation
    intTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom runtimeOnly
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.2'
    intTestImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.2'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    description = 'Runs integration tests.'
    group = 'verification'

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.intTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.intTest.runtimeClasspath
    shouldRunAfter test
}

check.dependsOn integrationTest
```

I've followed a [guide by Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests). When I faced the issue, I tried the following:
- Run `./gradlew cleanIntegrationTest integrationTest` to bypass IntelliJ but it still ran 0 tests
- Add [the idea Gradle plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064377/mark-gradle-source-folder-as-test-source-in-intellij).
- Add `dependsOn` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061774/run-single-integration-test-with-gradle).
- Solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741004/adding-an-additional-test-suite-to-gradle).

How can I enable Gradle to discover tests inside the source set "intTest"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test is a JUnit 5 test, but you haven't told Gradle. Just like for the test task you need to call

```
useJUnitPlatform()
```

in the configuration of your `integrationTest` task.

Comment: trivial comment/addition, but I solved this using to avoid specifying things twice (only sharing if it helps someone else.  ```tasks.withType(Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}```